# How to access a windows command line from a linux machine?

Tags: ssh, command-line-interface, telnet

How to access the windows command line from an ubuntu machine.
OS in question is Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04.
Accessing here refers to remote access.

Comment: If this really is production setup related, you could opt for Powershell web access: http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2012/11/05/windows-8-windows-server-2012-windows-powershell-web-access.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Several ways:

1. Run an ssh server on the Windows host, and connect to it with an ssh client. There are lots of ssh servers that you can buy for Windows, but [Cygwin](http://cygwin.com) includes the free OpenSSH server.  However, that will get you a Linux shell when you connect to it.
2. Run Windows Terminal Services, and connect to it with a Remote Desktop client.  That will give you a remote desktop, where you can start a Windows command line, Cygwin shell, or any other programs.
3. Run the Windows telnet service, and connect to it with a telnet client.

Comment: Both the machines are different.I am not emulating any of the OS'es.And by running the SSH server i will get a linux terminal itself.I need access to the native windows command prompt .

Comment: It sounds as though you want option 2 or 3 (which I just added) then.  Or, maybe one of the Windows ssh servers will give you a CMD or PowerShell instead of a Linux shell.

Comment: The RDP protocol lets you specify the shell; it's explorer by default but you can set it to, eg, PowerShell (I've done that) and probably even cmd (never tried that, though). It's an option on every Linux RDP client I've seen.

Comment: Cool, thanks Bandrami.  Sounds like the solution then.

Comment: I know about the remote desktop but the i want a solution like telnet where only the terminal is the means of the communication.And i dont know about the RDP protocol can you please tell how to run RDP ? I have tried the third option beforehand but thats not working "Server refused connection"

Comment: We gave you three answers, and you don't seem to like any of them.  But those are the methods.  Go research them and try them, and if you have problems with them come back and ask a more specific question.

Comment: Its not about liking my friend the remote desktop solution is always there.I am looking for something like a telnet or an ssh session and the telnet session is straightaway refused.I cannot help it.My guess is it cannot be done!

Comment: It cannot be done without RDP.!

Answer (score 1):

Set up a Windows 2012 server as a [Powershell Remote Access gateway](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2012/11/05/windows-8-windows-server-2012-windows-powershell-web-access.aspx). Connect to powershell on the gateway and execute remote powershell commands on other machines such as your Windows 7 machine.

If you want a native telnet like remote commandline then [install telnet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732046(v=ws.10).aspx) (I'm not saying it is a good solution, just a solution) or a third party solution. [Execute powershell commands from within cmd.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16493974/how-to-execute-powershell-commands-not-from-ps1-file-from-cmd-exe), there are quite a few options for doing that. I suggest to google to your hearts content.